# django runserver giving error for libmysqlclient_18 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.18

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7, mariadb

on running django-server with django==1.9 and pgsql 9.5, virtualenv=15.0.9 with python2.7 installation no-wheel no-site-packages on ubuntu 14.04

no previous mysql installation prior mariadb==10.2 after which this error occured. tried purging mariadb then, installing mysql=5.6 from dpkg but it didn't solved it either, then reinstalled mariadb==10.2 for `sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient` but it didn't solved it either.
Any help would be appreciated, ....
getting the below error

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
a gis plugin was being used in my project postgis and postgres used in project.
for that the very initial postgres installation must have put libmysqlclient_18 version defined by its own customizations.
after mariadb installation, the libmysqlclient.so.18 should have been updated, hindering the older linkage and setups.

ran the mysql/mariadb cleaning with this post
https://askubuntu.com/a/172516/735971

installed mariadb again, got the gis support and issue is resolved.
link to gis support libraries:
http://scigeo.org/articles/howto-install-latest-geospatial-software-on-linux.html

update:
got another error during running django server with postgresql==9.5 and postgis==2.2
Could not find the GEOS library (tried "geos_c", "GEOS"). Try setting GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.

traced to evidence that mariadb-common files and libmysqlclient/libmariadblclient was still cached in apt-get
evertime I installed postgresql or any of its extension now, it used the cached copy of libmysqlclient.so.18 from mariadb.
so I removed all the unused dpkg configs
`sudo dpkg --purge`COLUMNS=300 dpkg -l "*" | egrep "^rc" | cut -d\  -f3

CAUTION: it can remove all the unused package, for only mariadb related files you can do
`sudo dpkg --purge`COLUMNS=300 dpkg -l "maria*" | egrep "^rc" | cut -d\  -f3

Also removed postgresql for the next clean installation overriding any traces of compiled libmysqlclient if any.
then removed any apt-repo related to mariadb from /etc/apt/sources.list followed by `sudo apt-get update`.
then apt-get autoremove and apt-get clean to clean everything.
then `sudo apt-get install -y postgresql-9.5 postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.2 postgresql-9.5-pgrouting postgresql-contrib-9.5`

but i must say mariadb V10.2 still clashes with other installations and system libraries like it clashed in prior versions for libmysqlclient.so